# Should I overwrite an existing variable in order to save memory in R

Tags: r, memory-management

Not very familiar with GC in R, just wondering if it could save some memory if I overwrite an existing variable in R. For example, a large vector add 1:

```
aa <- rnorm(100000)
# method 1: create a new variable
bb <- aa + 1
# method 2: overrite previous variable
aa <- aa + 1
```

Method 1 created a new variable, and occupied some memories. What about method 2, will it need more memories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lobstr` package (which supersedes `pryr`) to explore memory usage and garbage collection in R. There's lots more to it [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html), but the short answer is that overwriting an existing variable takes up much less additional memory than creating a new variable. I use `pryr` below due to the convenience of the `mem_change` function unavailable in `lobstr`.

```r
library(pryr)

aa <- rnorm(100000)

# method 1: create a new variable
mem_change(bb <- aa + 1)
#> 805 kB

# method 2: overrite previous variable
mem_change(aa <- aa + 1)
#> 528 B
```